# Cosuming data from a REST API to ASP;NET CORE(Angular ASP.NET CORE project)

Tags: angular, rest, api, asp.net-core, prometheus

I have created an Angular project with visual studio, I'm using ASP.NET CORE 3.1 as my backend and Angular 9.0.1 as my FRONT-END.
I have tried to consume data from a REST API(Prometheus API), here is the model:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Prometheus_test.v1
    {
        public class Query
        {
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public object Data { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

and my Controller looks like:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Prometheus_test.v1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class QueryController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<QueryController> _logger;

        public QueryController(ILogger<QueryController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<QueryController> Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Query> Queries = null;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9090/api/v1/");
                //HTTP GET
                var responseTask = client.GetAsync("query?query=up&time=2020-02-20T10:30:00.781Z");
                responseTask.Wait();

                var result = responseTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<Query>>();
                    readTask.Wait();

                    Queries = readTask.Result;
                }
                else //web api sent error response 
                {
                    //log response status here..

                    Queries = Enumerable.Empty<Query>();

                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error. Please contact administrator.");
                }
            }

            return View(Queries);

        }
    }
}
```

Now I dont know what to do I'm very confused, will I get the data using this model? and how can I consume the data from this REST API ?
Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You'll need to post the Angular code you have attempted so far if you want specific help with that

Comment: Where's your angular code? What have you tried in angular and didn't work for now?

Comment: In you code, we can find you return a view in your API controller action, can you clairfy more about the scenario and requirement of your Angular client app?

Comment: The [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) in @angular/common/http offers a simplified client HTTP API for Angular applications, you can make request to your back-end service from your Angular front-end.

Comment: I didnt create the angular component yet,I just put a "Console.Write" to see what was the result but it didnt work, I want a guide or something to help me know what should be the type of return so that it can be redirect to the user ( whos using one of the component ).

Comment: Based on the code of your API action, we can find you make request to another APIs `http://localhost:9090/api/v1/` to get data. Before you implement angular client, you could make request to your API from browser (or postman etc) then debug your API code and check if you can got expected data.